# Static implementation of an object scoped method in java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, boilerplate, aop

Hi : I have a class defining the following method :

```
public String abstract getAnimalName();
```

And a subclass

```
class Ralph extends Animal
{
    public String getAnimalName(){return "RALPH";}
}
```

I want "Ralph"'s getAnimalName to be static, since there is only one, stateless
version of Ralph's name.

Thus, I want to implement the getAnimalName statically, whilst still satisfying the interface.  Is this possible ?  Maybe, is there a way I can use a dependency injection or AOP technique to provide the object implementation by proxying the static one at run time ?

The obvious solution (of having an object scope method wrap a static method) is a little to boiler-plateish for my tastes.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, your last suggestion is all you can do.

This might be a warning that something is suspicious in the design.

Ralph is an instance, and as such needs to obey the contract of `getAnimalName`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be best doing:

```
class Ralph extends Animal { 

    private static final String NAME = "RALPH";

    public String getAnimalName(){return NAME;} 
}
```

You may also make `NAME` public if you want.

Comment: For it to be accessible outside of Ralph, you'll need it to another scope - and I'd suggest making NAME final to prevent modification.

Answer (score 1):

The design needs to be reviewed for sure. If you're happy with the architecture, I would turn the class into a singleton and use Ralph.getInstance().getAnimalName().

Perhaps consider annotations for this?

```
@Name("RALPH")
class Ralph extends Animal
{}
```

You can pull annotations off the Class object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations()

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your code to the next way:

```
class Ralph extends Animal
{
    public static String NAME = "RALPH";
}

class Animal {
    public static String NAME;

}
```

more than use your **getAnimalName()** method.

Comment: i believe this is dangerous i believe it hides rather than overrides the var?

Comment: You probably want the NAME in Ralph final too.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a concept of more than one instance of a method. It wont add any extra memory when you create multiple `Ralph` objects.

You might, however, want to create a meta-type.